# php -v shows 7 on terminal, but when we check on browser it is 5.5.9

Tags: php, version, upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, I have upgraded the PHP 5.5.9 to 7 by [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04) instructions. When I check `php -v` on terminal then I can see the version is 7 and when I check on browser I can see that php version is 5.5.9. Can you tell me how I can fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Restart Apache to be sure you don't just need to restart Apache.

Comment: Fail to restart Apache2

Comment: You were unable to restart Apache2?

Comment: Yes, 
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail]

Comment: please post more info on your hosting setup. are you using mod_php or php cgi?  also run phpinfo(); and see more about your php version in the webserver.  it sounds like you only ran the commands to update php on the commandline and not for apache.

Comment: Yes, I run on the PHP upgrade on command line, how can I run for Apache ?
I am getting following message when I try to restart apache,
AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ioss-All-Series
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, I think I am using mod_php. Don't know much more about it

Comment: Yes, I can restart the Apache now.